# Proof by cases on a boolean expression in Coq

Tags: coq

I have a contains function:

```
Fixpoint contains (l: list string) (x: string): bool :=
  match l with
  | [] => false
  | h :: tl => (if (string_dec h x) then true else (contains tl x))
  end.
```

which checks if a string is in a list of strings. I would like to prove a theorem by doing case analysis on whether `contains (vars e) y` holds. However, when I destruct on this boolean I don't get any extra hypothesis for the different subcases.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the corresponding assumptions, use "eqn" to give a name for them. that is: 
`destruct (contains (vars e) y) eqn:name.`

Comment: the lemma doesnt go through by induction on vars e. It goes by case analysis. However, the branches of the case analysis do not receive the corresponding assumption, i.e. contains (vars e) y = true or contains (vars e) y = false

Comment: If you want to get the corresponding assumptions, use "eqn" to give a name for them. that is: destruct (contains (vars e) y) eqn:name.

Comment: indeed, that was the problem

Comment: Dear @xiajie, can you edit the answer to add the information that you included in the comment?  I think the information about `:eqn` is the crucial bit.